# How to add custom claims in OidcProviderConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to add the new claim ("**end_session_endpoint**") in OidcProviderConfiguration because UI needs to get that claim, besides the default ones, in **/.well-known/openid-configuration** response.

**Is that possible?**

**Note**: I'm using Spring Authorization Server version 0.2.2

Answer (score 2):

It's not yet possible (as of this writing), but very close! Take a look at [Ability to modify OIDC provider configuration #616](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/616) to follow progress on this issue.

Comment: Tnx Steve, that helped me a lot.